# Automapper CreateMissingTypeMaps property Warning

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I think this is a repeated Question but i am unable to resolve it.
here is my mapping.

```
UserProfileVM model = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<UserProfileVM>(objUser);
```

But here `AutoMapper` gives warning.

I tried to add `MapperConfiguration`, but i have no idea how to use it in `DynamicMap<>()`.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true; });
```

Now how to use my **config** variable for dynamic map?

Or is there any global setting for these issue because i used mapper for many times in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize static AutoMapper using a certain configuration (recommended for the usage you have show):

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true);
```

Or create instance of AutoMapper from a configuration:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true; });
IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

[AutoMapper Static and Instance API](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Static-and-Instance-API#unsupported-operations)

Comment: If you go for `Mapper.Initialize`, you should be able to call DynamicMap on the static AutoMapper as you have shown in your example: `UserProfileVM model = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<UserProfileVM>(objUser);`

Comment: Static API is now obsolete in AutoMapper 9.0