# Automapper: map an anonymous/dynamic type

Tags: c#-4.0, automapper-5

I need some help to map an anonymous object using Automapper. The goal is combine Product and Unity in a ProductDto (in which unity is a product's property).

Autommaper `CreateMissingTypeMaps` configuration is set to `true`.

**My Classes:**

```
public class Product 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Unity 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDto 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public UnityDto Unity{ get; set; }
}

public class UnityDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Test Code**

```
Product p = new Product() { Id = 1 };
Unity u = new Unity() { Id = 999 };
var a = new { Product = p, Unity = u };

var t1 = Mapper.Map<ProductDto>(a.Product); 
var t2 = Mapper.Map<UnityDto>(a.Unity);
var t3 = Mapper.Map<ProductDto>(a); 

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ProductId: {0}", t1.Id)); // Print 1
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("UnityId: {0}", t2.Id)); // Print 999
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Anonymous ProductId: {0}", t3.Id)); // Print 0 <<< ERROR: It should be 1 >>>
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Anonymous UnityId: {0}", t3.Unity.Id)); // Print 999
```

There are two maps added to the profile:

```
CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>();
CreateMap<Unity, UnityDto>();
```

Comment: this answer says to pass the setting in when calling `Map`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085878/automapper-auto-create-createmap, but that is with known types.

Comment: The CreateMissingTypeMaps was already working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how Automapper map anonymous objects. I haven't time to check out Automapper source code but I got the desired behaviour with minor changes on my anonymous object:

```
var a = new { Id = p.Id, Unity = u };
```

By doing this, I might even delete previous mappings because now it is using only `CreateMissingTypeMaps`.

**Note:** As matter of fact I'm not sure if it is really an issue or I it was just my unreal expectations.